# Change Selected in dropdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following drop-down:

```
<select size="1" name="foo" id="foo" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <option value="bla1;" class=" nAll" selected="1">Requests</option>
    <option value="bla2;" class=" nAll">Requests Rate</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to change the select option with the following code:

```
      var url = window.location.href;
        var i=1
        var value=getUrlParameter(url);
        $("#foo").find('option').each(function(){
        if(value === i){
            $(this).attr("selected","1");
            }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr("selected","0");    
        }
        i++;
    }
);
```

Basically i have a parameter that I sent in the URL and I want to set the drop-down correctly when I reload the page.

For some reason this is whats happening when I run the code:

```
<select size="1" name="foo" id="foo" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <option value="bla1;" class=" nAll" selected="selected">Requests</option>
    <option value="bla2;" class=" nAll" selected="selected">Requests Rate</option>
</select>
```

what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
<select size="1" name="foo" id="foo" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <option value="bla1;" class=" nAll" selected="0">Requests</option>
        <option value="bla2;" class=" nAll" selected="1">Requests Rate</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the name of the parameter ? Is it "url" ?

Comment: You have to set the option at the position of the number as selected right ?

Comment: I'm getting a number from the URL and the number should be the selected option.

Comment: What is the parameter name ? Is it like this http://somesite.com?number=1

Comment: yes, then value= 1

Answer (score 0):

The value passed in to the `getUrlParameter` method should be a string. But it has been passed as `url` variable value.

```js
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

var url = window.location.href;
var i=1
var value=getUrlParameter("value"); //Change it to variable name in url within double quotes.
$("#foo").find('option').each(function(){
    if(value == i)
    {
        $(this).attr("selected",true);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).attr("selected",false);    
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="1" name="foo" id="foo" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <option value="bla1;" class=" nAll" selected="1">Requests</option>
    <option value="bla2;" class=" nAll">Requests Rate</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the "porp" atribute as following:

to find current selected option:

```
("#foo").prop("selectedIndex")
```

to set a dropdown:

```
("#foo").prop("selectedIndex",optionIndex)
```